# Is it better to allocate memory using a pointer to its struct, or the struct itself?

Tags: c, malloc

I got the same values by replacing the line marked with (1) in my actual code with:

```
Date *ptrdate = malloc(12 * sizeof(*ptrdate));
```

**Question:** Which one is better and why?

Here is my actual code:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int mo;
} Date;

void main(){
    Date *ptrdate = malloc(12 * sizeof(Date)); //(1)

    ptrdate[0].day=26;
    ptrdate[0].mo=5;
    printf("Date:%d/%d\n", ptrdate[0].day, ptrdate[0].mo);
}
```

Comment: The only acceptable return type of `main()` in C is `int`.

Comment: @Amessihel I have updated the question to make it clear. Shall we delete the comment chain? [This message will self-destruct in 1 min...]:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing your code as

```
Date *ptrdate = malloc(12 * sizeof(*ptrdate));
```

or, a cleaner approach

```
Date *ptrdate = malloc(12 * sizeof *ptrdate);  //sizeof is operator, no need for extra "()"
```

is more acceptable and desirable, as it makes code more robust. Even if

- the type of `ptrdate` gets changed in future
- using the code along with any external library which has a seperate`typedef`ed `Date` (creating a conflict)<sup>[#]</sup>

you don't need to change this part(s) of code.

Also, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

---

<sup>[#]Thanks to Mr. **@Elias Van Ootegem** for the comment below]</sup>

Comment: sorry @iharob, was editing at the same time. However, i've incorporated your changes. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the recommended signature should be int main(void) as opposed to int main(int argc, char *argv[])?

Comment: Also, `sizeof` is not a function so drop the pointless parentheses when possible. `Date *ptrdate = malloc(12 * sizeof *ptrdate);`.

Comment: @Cubia `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` can be used when you intend to make use of command line arguments. If you don't need them , `int main(void)` will do fine. Refer chapter `5.1.2.2.1`, `C11` standard.

Comment: @unwind Thanks for the suggestion sir. Updated accordingly. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Next to the actual variable changing type, name conflicts requiring the `typedef` to change is another reason to prefer `sizeof *ptr` over `sizeof(Type)` cf my answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Very right sir. I'll add a line to my answer to reflect your comment, with your permission. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is more the matter of taste/style. I'd prefer `sizeof(Date)` as this seems a little more readable to me. But just do as you like - no real difference here.

Comment: `sizeof(type)` might put you at risk of having to refactor all code that allocates memory for your struct if you decide to change the `typedef` statement (because of a name conflict with some third party dependency, for example). That's why I think most people would prefer `sizeof *ptr_var`, that and not having as many brackets

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Well, it's not an everyday issue. And one still needs search&replace if run into it. So the risks seem to be overestimated.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem BTW. I like brackets :-)

Comment: It's not an everyday scenario when working on _existing code_, agreed. When developing something new, it does happen (at least, when I'm doing the developing it has happened). BTW: Brackets are OK, but I don't want my C code to look like lisp :-P